# Store [value] contents from browser element as a string

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I have a quick question regarding being able to store parts of an element as a string which I can later recall.

Example:
I have an element that looks like this

`<input type= "hidden" name="Posted" id="Posted" value="100|307|151|16">`

I can retrieve the element with `document.getElementById('#Posted')` and now I want to be able to take the contents in the [value] tag and store them as a string in a new variable, so I can get something like this:

`var inputValue = "100|307|151|16"`

Which I can later recall in my code.
Maybe I'm blind but after a bit of searching I've still come up with nothing. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
 //If all you care about is the value, you can just use .value to get the information you want
const inputValue = document.getElementById('#Posted').value;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's two different approaches you can take here.

You can either [get the value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) of the hidden input, or you can [get the value of the "value" attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) on the hidden input.

Here's how to do both:

```
var element = document.getElementById('Posted');

var value = element.value;
var attribute = element.getAttribute("value");

console.log(`value: ${value}`);
console.log(`attribute: ${attribute}`);
```

And here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bfuw8jaz/) of that in action.

Comment: *Isn't your answer basically the same as the two others?* Pretty much but with a handful of important differences. I supplied explanations, sources for documentation, a working example, and my code works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
var inputValue = document.getElementById('#Posted').getAttribute("value");
```